# 2012 RDS SERVER SSL CERTIFICATE ISSUE - Moving from Self Signed

Tags: ssl, rds

I have a 2012 R2 RDS server. Previously we used a locally self signed certificate to allow clients to setup Remote App and Desktop connections. This certificate was not able to be extended and so expired. We purchased a SSL certificate and gave it FQDN of server.companyname.co.uk. The RDS server is called server.companyname.local. On setting up new clients we get an error saying certificate is in one name and server name is different. However setup will complete. But when remote app programs are run they fail because says certificate is in one name and server name connecting to is different.

I imagine this issue has been encountered by everyone who has moved from self signed to 3 party SSL on a RDS.

I have a work around but would like a proper solution to this.

Thanks

Paul,

Answer (score 0):

If the certificate subject name is server.companyname.co.uk, that is the name that must be used to use to connect.  If that name does not exist in DNS, create it.

Comment: Added to DNS on DC.

Comment: I imagine similar issues for anyone using .local as their domain, If you want anything other than a self signed cert then you will hit this problem,

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for this: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Change-published-FQDN-for-2a029b80

It has to do with the name provided in the Remote Connection details will still be set to the .local hostname.

Comment: Jarrett, Brilliant, exactly what I was looking for, thanks